# How to delete and update specific item in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, get, put

I have connect my reactive form app with REST API, and when I try to delete hotel it show me  Really delete the Hotel: (undefined)? 
it does not see the id of clicked hotel, what is the problem of my code? 
how I can fix it

This is the delete function:

```
    deleteHotel(): void {
    if (this.hotel.ID === 0) {
    // Don't delete, it was never saved.
    this.onSaveComplete();
     } else {
    if (confirm(`Really delete the Hotel: ${this.hotel.hotelName}?`)) {
    this.hs.deleteHotel(this.hotel.ID)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.onSaveComplete()

    );
    }
   }
   }
```

and here is the .html form:

```
  <form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(rHotelForm)" [formGroup] = "rHotelForm">
  <input type="hidden" formConrolName="id"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label >Hotel Name</label>
      <input id="hotelNameId" class="form-control" type="text" 
     formControlName="hotelName"/>

    </div> 



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label >Phone</label>
          <input class="form-control"formControlName="phone">
        </div> </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label >Number of rooms</label>
                      <input class="form-control" formControlName="numberOfRooms" >
                    </div> </div>

                      <div class=" col-md-6">
                        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" [disabled] ="!rHotelForm.valid">Submit</button>
                      </div> 
                      <div class=" col-md-6">
                          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary" (click) ="resetForm(hotelForm)">Reset</button>
                        </div> 






</form> 
<br> Value : {{rHotelForm.value | json}}
  <form [formGroup] = "hotelForm">

   <ul><li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">

    <span>
        <a class="btn" (click)="deleteHotel()">
        Hotel ID :{{hotel.ID}} Hotel Name : {{hotel.hotelName}} 
   </a>
      </span>

</li></ul>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary" (click) 
 ="deleteHotel(hotel.ID)">Delet Hotel</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You have two functions with same name _deleteHotel_ but different arguments? Which is the correct one?

Comment: without argument

Comment: Do you have global variable _hotel_ in your TS? I can see you are using _this.hotel_ in your code. And what does deleteHotel(hotel.ID) do?

Comment: @Arcteezy yes there are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's work when I replace deleteHotel() by getHotel(hotel.ID) then add a delete hotel .

this is the getHotel method:

```
    getHotel(id: number) {
 this.hs.getHotel(id).subscribe(
hotel => this.hotel = hotel,
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

from the below code what i understood is you are trying to delete the hotel but not passing it to the delete function as it has list of hotels and you are trying to delete one hotel which you did not paas to the function because of which it is showing undefined

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">

    <span>
        <a class="btn" (click)="deleteHotel()">
        Hotel ID :{{hotel.ID}} Hotel Name : {{hotel.hotelName}} 
   </a>
      </span>

</li></ul>
```

deleteHotel(): void {
 }

**instead of this use below code**

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">

        <span>
            <a class="btn" (click)="deleteHotel(hotel)">
            Hotel ID :{{hotel.ID}} Hotel Name : {{hotel.hotelName}} 
       </a>
          </span>

    </li></ul>
 deleteHotel(hotel): void {
    if (hotel.ID === 0) {
    // Don't delete, it was never saved.
    this.onSaveComplete();
     } else {
    if (confirm(`Really delete the Hotel: ${hotel.hotelName}?`)) {
    this.hs.deleteHotel(hotel.ID)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.onSaveComplete()

    );
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: @Noor Shaker does `hotel` object contains `hotelName`?

Comment: @KiraAG yes it contain it

Comment: can you console.log hotel  in delete method and show us the result?

Comment: See there lies the answer. You don't have any properties inside Hotel{}.

Comment: try this


`deleteHotel(id: number) {

       this.hs.getHotel(id).subscribe(

       hotel => this.hotel = hotel;
if (hotel.ID === 0) {
    // Don't delete, it was never saved.
    this.onSaveComplete();
     } else {
    if (confirm(`Really delete the Hotel: ${hotel.hotelName}?`)) {
    this.hs.deleteHotel(hotel.ID)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.onSaveComplete()

    );
    }
  )}
`